# How to reload captcha without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<img id="imgCaptcha" src="SandCaptcha.aspx?CHA=0azSeOdr7S7gTkFxtL6/5B6h2vj+naZnDR5jl/dvceoJHNXcooHfP2MkoWxPRVWvdK7NJHckH" style="height:60px;width:160px;">
```

```
  (function() {
    'use strict';
    function atualiza() {
document.querySelector('.captcha').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('yolo');
  var id = imgCaptcha();
  this.setAttribute('src', 'SandCaptcha.aspx?id=' + id);
});
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

How can I reload this captcha image without reloading page, with the help of JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

`Try adding ?t='+new Date().getTime()` to your setAttribute. `this.setAttribute('src', 'SandCaptcha.aspx?id=' + id + '?t='+new Date().getTime());` This should force the image to reload instead of using the cache.